# Ruby version mismatch after ruby upgrade without rvm or rbenv

Tags: ruby, capistrano, unicorn, bluepill, ruby-upgrade

I am using bluepill to manage unicorn and after ruby upgrade unicorn start is failing with below error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:495:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.1.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.7 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:470:in `validate_runtime!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
E, [2019-02-20T10:42:13.897013 #10437] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 12149 exit 1> exec()-ed
```

The strange thing is it fails only when it is invoked via capistrano deployment. It runs fine if I run it manually on the server. I tried all sort of things but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance.

Bluepill confiuguration for running unicorn:

```
Bluepill.application(APPLICATION_NAME) do |application|
  application.working_dir = "/var/apps/APPLICATION_NAME/current"

  process "unicorn" do
    start_command    "/usr/local/bin/bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E qa -D"
    environment      ({

      "RAILS_ENV"  => "qa",
      "RACK_ENV"   => "qa"
    })
    pid_file         "/var/apps/APPLICATION/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"
    cache_actual_pid false
    stop_command     "kill -QUIT {{PID}}"
    restart_command  "kill -USR2 {{PID}}"

    start_grace_time   60.seconds
    stop_grace_time    20.seconds
    restart_grace_time 13.seconds

    checks :flapping, :times => 2, :within => 30.seconds, :retry_in => 7.seconds

    monitor_children do
      stop_command "kill -QUIT {{PID}}"

      checks :mem_usage, :every => 10.seconds, :below => 500.megabytes, :times => [3,4], :fires => :stop
      checks :cpu_usage, :every => 10.seconds, :below => 20, :times => [3,4], :fires => :stop
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you specify ruby version in your `Gemfile` ?

Comment: @zeitnot Yes, it is 2.3.7.

Comment: Is this a rails project?

Comment: what is `/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/` ? add code which shows how blupill is running unicorn, and what you did to trigger the error

Comment: @lacostenycoder - This is the old ruby configuration. Updated question description with bluepill configuration.

Comment: what about capfile?  you said it only happens with cap deploy

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear:  `Your Ruby version is 2.1.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.7`

Did you check the ruby version in your Gemfile?  It should match the ruby version you're using and you'll likely need to run

```
bundle update
```

and

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Hi, i am using ruby 2.3.7 and everywhere it is same. It used to be 2.1.4 and then I upgraded it to 2.3.7.

Comment: @vikram what do you mean by "everywhere" ?

Comment: means it's a system-wide installed ruby version.